# Wrap multiple Chip create an overflow - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, overflow, word-wrap

In way to create the profil page on my app, I have this sample of code :

```
return Container(
          height: 30.h,
          child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const ProfilPic(),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5.w,
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      data['pseudo'],
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Membre depuis : $userCreationDateFormatted',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineLarge,
                    ),
                    data['role'] == 'admin'
                        ? const Text(
                            'Administrateur',
                          )
                        : Container(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 2.h,
                    ),
                    Wrap(children: [
                      Chip(
                        label: Text(
                          '#${data['fav_genre']}',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Chip(
                        label: Text(
                          '#${data['pref']}',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Chip(
                        label: Text(
                          '#${data['top_']}',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Chip(
                        label: Text(
                          data['top_anime'],
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                  ],
                )
              ]));
```

**The problem is that I have an overflow, even with the 'Wrap' widget.**

I think there is something wrong with the main Container because when I try my code in another part of my app, it work fine. But I can't figure out why.
I even try to wrap the 'Wrap' with a 'SingleChildScrollView' but it does not work.

[image: preview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a `Row` widget, and inside a `Column` that holds (among other widgets) the `Wrap` widget. This way the row does not know how many space to allocate to your `Column` widget.

Once you solve this, `Wrap` will do it's job to make the chips go to multiple lines.

You need the wrap your `Column` into an `Expanded` widget. This tells the framework that after profile picture and the spacer `SizedBox` is added to the `Row`, the rest of the available place should be occupied by your `Column`:

```
children: [
  const ProfilPic(),
  SizedBox(width: 5.w),
  Expanded(child: Column(...)),
],
```

(Note: there is another problem with your current layout: you are giving the `Container` a fixed height. This way if the contents don't fit you will have another bottom overflow problem.)

Comment: Nice Thanks ! It's working fine.
Thanks also for your tip about Container ! I'll see that, for now it was just for some layout tests.